# Function $f \geq 0$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $f : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R} $ is integrable (with respect to measure $\mu$) and for every measurable set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have $\int_{E} f d \mu \geq 0$.  Prove that $f \geq 0$ a.e.

My question is this: if I suppose toward a contradiction that $f \not\geq 0$ a.e., does that mean that there exists a measurable set $S$ such that $f < 0$ on $S$ and $m(S) > 0$?

Comment: yes, it does mean exactly that, and this is a good way of proving this statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. When in doubt, go back to the definition.

$f\geq 0 \ a.e$ means that $\mu ( \{x:  f(x) < 0 \} ) = 0$

So the negation of this property is that $\mu ( \{x:  f(x) < 0 \} ) > 0$